# Does half pressing a RS-80N3 trigger autofocus if back-button AF is enabled?

Tags: canon, autofocus, remote

I'm looking to invest in a remote trigger say the RS-80N3 or alike for my Canon DSLRs. I'm using them all with back-button AF enabled (and half press shutter autofocus disabled) and I wonder if half pressing the remote would trigger the same effect as half pressing the shutter or if it will trigger the autofocus too. If it just corresponds to half pressing the shutter I wouldn't have to turn the lens to manual focus during time lapses and manual bracketing of photos.

Comment: Note that with Canon DSLRs you can enable back button AF without disabling AF on a shutter half press, so the answer to your question really depends on whether or not you have AF on shutter button half press enabled as well or not in addition to back button.

Comment: @MichaelClark I forgot to add that. Half pressing the shutter won't trigger autofocus. It's added now.

Answer (score 1):

No, the half press of the remote is the same as a half press of the shutter button.

I suppose this makes sense for a landscape shooter who doesn't want to mess up his focus when using the cable release, but can be annoying for other uses.

Would be nice if the cable release buttons could be reassigned like the others in the menu, but I think internally they just short cut the real shutter buttons.

Answer (score 0):

According to this product listing for the Canon Remote Switch RS-80N3, "The Remote Switch works just like a shutter button, enabling halfway or complete pressing."

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/164276-REG/Canon_2476A001_Remote_Switch_RS_80N3.html

(I'm not affiliated with the above store)